# HTML5 validation on form with btn that trigger JS function to send php mail and show modal when success

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have form on my website, when I click the button I trigger a JS function that take the inputs from my form and send a mail using php. After the mail are sent a modal is showing a thanks for contact. Everything works perfect until I try to validate the form using "HTML5 required". And if I use the submit form the validation works but not my modal. This drives me crazy and it must be some easy solution that I miss. I have search a lot but don't find any solution that's fits my issue.

BR
Mats

MY HTML

```
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required placeholder="Ditt namn:"><br>                  
    <input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" required placeholder="Din e-post:"><br>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" required placeholder="Ditt telefonnummer:"><br>                   
    <textarea name="message" id="message" required placeholder="Ditt meddelande:" rows="10"></textarea>                 
    <table>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="checkbox" required ></td><td>
    <label for="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;Jag har läst och godkänner news <a onclick="showModal('intrigitetspolicyModal')">integritetspolicy</a></label>
   </td> <br>
    </table>
    <input id="buttonMail" type='button'  onclick=”sendMail()” value='Skicka'/>               
    </form>
```

My JS

```
  function sendMail(){

    var data = {
        name: $("#name").val(),
        mail: $("#mail").val(),
        phone: $("#phone").val(),
        message: $("#message").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "javaScript/mail.php",
        data: data,

        success: function(){
        }

    });

    showModal('kontaktModal');
    $("#formMail").trigger('reset');
    return false;

}

function showModal(Modal){
    var modal = document.getElementById(Modal);
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

MY PHP

```
<?php
```

if($_POST){

```
$to = "example@example";
$subject = "Medelande från example";
$subject2 = "Kopia på det formulär du skicka på example";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$from = $_POST['mail'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $name .  " skrev:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'] . "\n\n"  . $_POST['name'] . "\n" . $_POST['mail'] . "\n" . $_POST['phone'];
$message2 = "Här är en kopia på ditt meddelande " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers2 = "From:" . $to;

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); //send email
mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
```

}
?>

Comment: How is your script failing when using `required`? How is `sendMail()` called?

Comment: Sorry it is onclick i have edit my post now... my script works but the validation does not. Validation works if i change button to submit but then page reload and my modal does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just need to call `reportValidity()` on your `sendMail()` function to benefit from the HTML5 validation without actually triggering the form submit.

Something like this should work for you:

```
function sendMail(){
    var isValid = document.querySelector('from').reportValidity();
    if (!isValid) {
        return false;
    }

    var data = {
        name: $("#name").val(),
        mail: $("#mail").val(),
        phone: $("#phone").val(),
        message: $("#message").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "javaScript/mail.php",
        data: data,

        success: function(){
        }

    });

    showModal('kontaktModal');
    $("#formMail").trigger('reset');
    return false;
}
```

See more info/example here: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/report-validity/

Comment: That was the solution i was looking for. Tank you so mutch, you made my day!!